# Events dont show on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I´m working with fullcalendar and google calendar, but the events don't appear on the day that I created.

I already did everything as described in the [official documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/).

Here is my code:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

At the end of the file:

```
<script src='assets/fullcalendar/moment.min.js'></script>
```

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            googleCalendarApiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            events: {
                googleCalendarId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                className: 'bg-purple'
            }
         });
     });

</script>
```

Comment: To update your code, use the `edit` link below your question. Don't put an answer unless you found an answer to your question.

Comment: You say you put moment.js at the end of the file. But it needs to be at the start, above where the fullcalendar.js is, as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/. Fix that, then check your browser console for any other errors, fix those (if any), and then see if it works.